# Get app data from Appstore build

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to be able to plug in any device that has my App on it and download the app data for my application. Is that possible?

I have a device that has the app store version of my application and I want to get the application data off of it.

I plugged in a device that is not added to my development account. I then add it to my dev account by going to Xcode organizer, selecting the device in the left-hand pane, and then clicking "Add to Member Center". After the whole process completes, I click Applications, but I don't see the existing app store version of my application available.

I then try to run my application on my device and it ends up deleting the existing App store version which causes all the data to be lost. Is there a way to get the existing app store app data off of the device?

===== edit ====

I'm looking to get the data manually, like I would if I had the app available as one of the options in the Applications tab underneath the device name in Xcode Organizer.

Comment: You've got several different questions here, some of which are too vague. For example you want to get the data manually or programatically. Have you at least looked at the iPhone Configuration Utility app?

Comment: [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) can pull your app data to your Mac or PC.

Comment: @bbarnhart iFunBox worked, can you send in an answer and I will upvote!